# Should "God" be capitalized in this instance?

Tags: meaning-in-context, religion

I notice quite a few writers (mainly Christian writers), always capitalizing the word God, even in sentences where, to me, it doesn't make grammatical sense.

For example: "God is a good God"; I do not feel capitalizing "god" in the second instance is necessary, and would be comparable to something like:

"The Ghost Train's biggest liability was being a Ghost Train".

In the second sentence, capitalizing "Ghost Train" the second time is incorrect.

So, is it gramatically correct to always capitalize "God" when referring to the Christian god?

Comment: As Christians only believe in one God (in three persons), the statement is puzzling. 'John Smith is a nice J/john S/smith.' But it does occur, so it's probably best to regard it as meaning 'God is good' (perhaps contrasting the truth with some theologies, where 'gods' have character flaws, petty feuds) (and which of us has never wondered how a good God can allow some of what goes on down here) and going with the users' preferences for capitalisation.

Answer (score 2):

When talking about Christianity, we would always capitalize the word as if it were a name.

When talking about members belonging to a category, such as the Greek gods and goddesses, it wouldn't be capitalized.

When talking about how different people/religions believe in different gods, it wouldn't be capitalized.

I am unaware which writer you are referring to, because his reference would imply the existence of many gods, but this doesn't have much to do with grammar or meaning in context.